# my function is skipping

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, recursive-algorithms, programming

I wrote a function in C code that calculates a polynomial value from a given array `arr[]` of `arrsize` size, where the elements are the coeffiecients.

the polynomial formula is:

$$p(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{arrsize - 1} a_ix^i$$

With $a_i$ the polynomial coefficients. The function needs to calculate the sum $s$:

$$s = \sum_{i = 0}^{arrsize - 1} p(a_i)$$

```
    int helper(int arr[], int arrsize, int x, int i)  /*helper function that calculates the value of the polynomial*/
    {    
        if (i==arrsize) 
    
        {return 0;}    
        else        
    {    
            printf("arr[%d] * %d^%d = %d\n", i, x, i, arr[i] * power_(x,i));    
            return arr[i]*power_(x,i) + helper(arr, arrsize, x,i+1);   
        }   
    }
    int sumOfEvaluations(int arr[], int arrsize) {
    
        if (arrsize == 0)     
        {return 0;}
        else {    
            return helper(arr, arrsize, arr[arrsize-1],0) + sumOfEvaluations(arr, arrsize-1);   
        }
    }
```

my problem is whenever i input an array, i don't get the result i want, for example for the array {1,2,3,4) the result should be 514, but the helper function skips part of the calculations.

i tried adding a print function before the recursive part of the function to see where it goes wrong, this is what it prints

```
    arr[0] * 4^0 = 1    
    arr[1] * 4^1 = 8    
    arr[2] * 4^2 = 48    
    arr[3] * 4^3 = 256    
    arr[0] * 3^0 = 1    
    arr[1] * 3^1 = 6    
    arr[2] * 3^2 = 27
```

it starts skipping here

```
    arr[0] * 2^0 = 1    
    arr[1] * 2^1 = 4    
    arr[0] * 1^0 = 1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should properly format your question because (1) it is not too much effort to understand markdown, and (2) it makes people more willing to understand your question. When you write the question, please pay attention to the tutorials on the right.

Comment: Thank you i didn't see the tutorial at first @Trebor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code it seems you are trying to recursively compute the value of a polynomial:

$$p(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} a_i \cdot x^i$$

If this is the case then your `helper` function will compute this value. Then you simply remove the recursive call in `sumOfEvaluations`  giving:

```
int sumOfEvaluations(int arr[], int arrsize, int x) {

    if (arrsize == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return helper(arr, arrsize, x, 0);
}
```

Now `sumOfEvaluations` computes the desired value.

Edit: It seems I initially misunderstood the problem. You do indeed want to evaluate the polynomials with the polynomial coefficients as input. In this case the following implementation will compute the desired value:

```
int func1(int arr[], int k, int i) {
    
    int res = 0;
    
    if(i < 0)
        return 0;
    
    res = arr[k] * pow(arr[i], k) + func1(arr, k, i - 1);
    
    return res;
}

int func2(int arr[], int k, int i) {
    
    int res = 0;
    
    if(k < 0)
        return 0;
    
    res = arr[k] * pow(arr[i], k) + func2(arr, k - 1, i);
    
    return res;
}

int sumOfEvaluations(int arr[], int arrsize) {
    
    int res = 0;
    
    if(arrsize < 0)
        return 0;
    
    res = res + func1(arr, arrsize - 1, arrsize - 1);
    res = res + func2(arr, arrsize - 2, arrsize - 1);
    
    res = res + sumOfEvaluations(arr, arrsize - 1);
    
    return res;
}
```

In the case you provided the above gives $514$ as output.

Comment: the problem is that i need the sumOfEvaluations to be recursive so removing the recursive call defeats the whole purpose, i also cant change the parameters, it needs to stay as sumOfEvaluations(int arr[], int arrsize), it;s whats making it hard

Comment: In that case what exactly is it that you would like to compute, since the current version of the question makes it seem as if you would like to determine the polynomial value of the coefficients defining that polynomial.

Comment: so the elements in the array are indeed the coefficients of the polynimal, so now i need the function to the values of the polynimal in which the 'x' are the elements of the array, aka the coefficients, and then add all those values to one sum, for ecample the array {1,2,3} would give me this polynmial p(x)=1+2x^1+3x^2, so what i need is the function to calculate p(1) and p(2) and p(3) and add them all together and get 53 i think

Comment: i'm sorry if the way i'm explaining makes it more complicated, i am struggling with trying to explain it in english lol

Comment: I have edited the answer and provided an implementation which satisfies the criteria you mentioned and computes the desired result.

Comment: very appreciated , but i can't use loops, sorry thats on me for not metioning, really im stuck with recursion, sincerely sorry

Comment: The first approach you followed would work if you can store the original value of ```arrsize```. Do you need to use C for this problem?

Comment: yeah it's gotta be on C

Comment: I've edited the code to remove all loops. Does it meet the requirements now :)?

Comment: yes! thank you so much you're a life saviour